# How to remove table border?

Tags: html, wordpress, html-table, border

I know there are many such posts, but none of the solutions works for me. I am using wordpress.com, which is extremely poor and has lots of flaws in general. So I just wonder if that is just one more "constraint" which wasn't mentioned along with the billing.

I have a simple HTML code, which works perfectly well in http://www.w3schools.com interpreter. It doesn't work when using wordpress.com.

```
<table border="0">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td align="center" width="90%">A</td>
    <td align="center">B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried `border-collapse` property as well. How to remove table borsers, or how to work around this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide demo/live link as it might be nested table issue..

Comment: @misery ..  only inspecting element and debbuging is the solution. There may some or other class which is getting applied. Or you can try using  : table{  border-collapse: collapse!important; border:none!important;}

Answer (score 2):

I found the tip which works. This is wordpress.com specific issue. Solution is given [here](https://wpbtips.wordpress.com/2010/06/15/overriding-table-borders/). It has to be stated

```
<table style="border:none;">
```

and in each cell

```
<td style="border:none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<table style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0">
```

You can also check your `styles.css` and see if there are specific styles for your table.

If you want to target a specific table then just use an ID or a class instead.

```
.table, .td, th {
     border: 0;
}
```

If still not working add `border: 0 !important;` and make sure that the css is rendered on your views by checking via inspect element...

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, and I cannot access styles.css.

Comment: can you give me the url then? check my update @Misery

Comment: How do I use the part you edited? Because when i use it in <style> tags it simply is diplayed on the www. I cannot give you url as it is only preview at the moment.

Comment: I am not allowed to publish it

Comment: styles.css inspected via firefox tools looks fine.

Comment: well can no longer help if you don't want to show your page.. can't just keep on blindly making suggestions.. if you can setup a demo or something then we'll work on that. :D

Comment: I know, but I wasn;t allowed to publish that. I just wondered if this is just yet another "feature" of wordpress.com, and yes it is. I am not very good in HTML, so your help was really great to me, as I got sure it is a wordpress.com issue, not my error.